# How to delete all Taxonomy terms of particular vocabulary using entity_delete_multiple?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, entities

I want to delete all taxonomy terms of particular vocabulary using `entity_delete_multiple`. For node it is working fine

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('type', 'page')
      ->execute();
  entity_delete_multiple('node', $result);
```

If i am changing taxonomy_term and type to `tags or any other vocabulary`, or replaced `type by bundle`

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
      ->condition('type', 'tags')
      ->execute();
  entity_delete_multiple('taxonomy_term', $result);
```

it is throwing error like this.

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: 'type' not found in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->ensureEntityTable() (line 304 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php).

And also i need a same query to delete user(s), watchdog and profiles.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Adding some current world context here, these days `entity_delete_multiple` is deprecated in Drupal 8 and is simply not present in Drupal 9.  Drush can always be used to accomplish the same end goal in a cross-major-version manner.  `drush entity:delete taxonomy_term --bundle=<the vocabulary bundle to delete>` will delete all terms in a specific vocabulary.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use `vid` instead of `type`. I haven't tried the code, but try the following

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
      ->condition('vid', 'tags')
      ->execute();
  entity_delete_multiple('taxonomy_term', $result);
```

[Here](http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/17/get-taxonomy-terms-of-a-vocabulary-drupal-8) is a good example for using entityQuery.

For deleting users, you can use `entity_delete_multiple` or `user_delete_multiple`

To delete user with uid 10

```
entity_delete_multiple('user', \Drupal::entityQuery('user')->condition('uid', '10', '=')->execute());
```

or pass an array of uids to `user_delete_multiple`

```
user_delete_multiple(array $uids);
```

I'm not aware of how to delete comments.

Comment: That's D7 documentation and not correct for 8.x

Comment: @Berdir thanks for pointing it out, I have removed the link and edited my answer

Comment: @Suresh: thanks for your answer.
And also is there any way to delete User(s), Profile and comments

Comment: @AAjayKumarReddy I have updated my answer. I'm not aware of how to delete comments.

Comment: @Suresh: What about profile? this is also entity right..

Comment: @AAjayKumarReddy I'm not aware of it too :(

Answer (score 7):

I know the question specifically asks about entity_delete_multiple, but the function is deprecated, scheduled to be removed "before" Drupal 9.  Here's a version without entity_delete_multiple

```
/**
 * Delete all taxonomy terms from a vocabulary
 * @param $vid
 */
function delete_terms_from_vocab($vid) {

  $tids = Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
    ->condition('vid', $vid)
    ->execute();

  if (empty($tids)) {
    return;
  }

  $term_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
  $entities = $term_storage->loadMultiple($tids);

  $term_storage->delete($entities);
}
```

Comment: Probably the best technique these days, but you probably want to rename $controller (which has a different meaning) to $storage.

Comment: `entityManager` is now `entityTypeManager`

Answer (score 3):

For taxonomy use `vid`:

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
      ->condition('vid', 'tags')
      ->execute();
```

Which is the bundle of taxonomy.

Answer (score 2):

For delete all taxonomy terms of particular vocabulary.

Try

```
 $vid = 'name_of_the_vocabulary';
      $tids = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
          ->condition('vid', $vid)
          ->execute();
      entity_delete_multiple('taxonomy_term', $tids);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code,which works for me

```
 $vids = Vocabulary::loadMultiple();
    foreach ($vids as $vid) {
      if ($vid->label() == 'YourVocab') {
        $container = \Drupal::getContainer();
        $terms = $container->get('entity.manager')->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid->id());
        if (!empty($terms)) {
          entity_delete_multiple('taxonomy_term', $terms);
        }
        break;
      }
}
```